# How to use FMDB with cocoapods and swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, fmdb

It looks like cocoapods supports FMDB:

```
pod 'FMDB/FTS'
```

But even after creating a bridging header I get the following error:

```
cocoapods bridging header error: 'FMDB.h' file not found
```

What's up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I also needed to add a header search path.

In your target's settings (not project settings) navigate to Build Settings -> Header Search Paths and add the following non-recursive path:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FMDB/src/fmdb"
```